# Difference between eqnarray and eqnarray*

Tags: equations, eqnarray

What is the difference between environments `eqnarray` and `eqnarray*` in a LaTeX input document?

Comment: Just a simple difference, one will number your equations, other dont. The starred version, doesnt number your equation(s).

Comment: `eqnarray` yields numbered equations, `eqnarray*` unnumbered. Anyway, the `amsmath` environments should be preferred, see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/82917).

Comment: @campa `amsmath` is a package, I think what you are meaning to say is the math environments within the `amsmath` package?

Comment: Why couldn't you try it in a small document?

Comment: numbered and unnumbered group of display equations, but please use align and align* environments with amsmath.sty